# cannot output session variable in json response

Tags: php, ajax

This is probably really simple but it isn't obvious to me right now why this isn't working.

I am setting a session variable on the index.php file, putting the value into a hidden field within a form and then submitting the form via jQuery and ajax. All the other form data is there and the hidden input value is there. But if I just try to echo the actual session variable out I get nothing eg:

```
$response['message'] = $_SESSION['csrf_token']; // no output

$response['message'] = $_POST['token']; // outputs the session variable value stored in the hidden field
```

On index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['csrf_token'] = uniqid('', true);
?>

 <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['csrf_token']; ?>">
```

jQuery:

```
var form = $('#testForm').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'test',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: form,
                beforeSend: function() {

                    // loading spinner etc.
                }
            })
```

Comment: where do you set the session? Have you called session_start() for this script?

Comment: @delboy1978uk, yes. I have updated my question

Comment: do you also session_start in the script where you say `$response['message'] = $_SESSION['csrf_token'];`?

Comment: @delboy1978uk, there. It was as I thought, something simple and stupid! That works now, cheers. If you post as answer I will mark as accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make sure the session has started on each script.

```
session_start();
$response['message'] = $_SESSION['csrf_token'];
$response['message'] = $_POST['token'];
```